# Как в TeeChart c++ builder поместить данные на график относительно временной шкалы?

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

Есть лог-файл, в котором каждая строка начинается с даты/времени и имеет фиксированную длину. т.е формат всегда один "число.месяц.год час:минута:секунда", после чего уже идут данные.

Нужно как-то сделать шкалу временную, которую можно приближать до секунд и ограничить обзор графика в рамках минимального и максимального времени.

Я это уже сделал, но через костыль, задав текстовый формат шкале и генерируя время в цикле, записывая его в вектор и в цикле расставляя своё время, на основе первого и последнего времени в лог-файле. Из этого всего создал сам себе много геморроя, поскольку данные расставляются правильно, но не получается вручную сделать то, что мне хочется. Например через событие onZoom я пытался задать инкрементирование на шкале, чтобы, к примеру, от 0 до 5 расстояние между метками было в 5 минут, от 6 до 10 было уже 2 минуты и т.д. Казалось бы, есть

```
Chart1->BottomAxis->Increment = 5;
```

но и оно не хочет работать (проверял на обычной шкале)

Элементарный пример:

```
Chart1->BottomAxis->Minimum = 0;
```

Он это игнорирует, всё равно можно перемещаться вдоль графика и увидеть отрицательные значения.

Так же в настройках самого графика указал минимальное значение даты, допустим "01.01.2023 00:00:00", но всё равно можно листать график чуть ли не до рождения Христа. Что делать-то вообще??? Как исправить ситуацию???

Answer (score 0):

```
CString cstr="соединение установлено"
SetDlgItemText(IDC_, cstr);
```

Вроде такого?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]